# Add items to array in typescript map

Tags: typescript

I have a JS Map that looks like this `let mappy = new Map<string, string[]>()`
I would like to add items to the array using the key and I could do this:

```
mappy.set(theKey, mappy.get(theKey).push('somevalue'));
```

that just seems like overkill to me. if I used a simple object I could easily just do

```
let mappy = {};
mappy[theKey] = [];
```

..and then later `mappy[theKey].push('somevalue')` but this kinda negates the typed object idea of TS

Is there any way i could add to that array in the map without first "getting" it?

Comment: Why `.set()` anything? You just need to `.get()` the array and `.push()` to it. In fact `.push()` returns a number - the new length of the array. So if you `.set(someKey, someArray.push())` you're setting the value of `someKey` to a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a reference to the array from the `Map` object and push extra values to it. There is no need to put it back in the `Map`, it already is there.

```js
mappy.get(theKey)!.push('somevalue');
```

The `!` after `mappy.get(theKey)` is needed because TypeScript complains that the value returned by `mappy.get()` can be `undefined`. The exclamation mark tells it that we know for sure that the value is defined. It is called a ["definite assigment assertion"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) and has been introduced in TypeScript 2.7.

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDnAnhAvBAdiA7hAsvAHgGcwAnAS3QHMAaCEi6gbQF0A+ACgEoBuAWABQoSGAAWIANIhkaAOQAzAPaLZ-AYNgJEAOiLgOYydLqteg4RAAeALnplKVVqmjwk2qvsNTEXCDCJ2jI4sahquOh5gBuLeXACE2nAArkSiHLJEilAgEABuMMBJILJmAppukdFGPgnJqemZ2RCKhqR5BUUloQIAxoromaDawIpUHOURnjHSXLxAA).

---

Or you can also use a plain object instead of a `Map`:

```js
type MyMap = { [K: string]: string[] };
let mappy: MyMap = {};

mappy[theKey] = [];
mappy[theKey].push('somevalue');
```

Comment: Thanks man..
I learned 3 new things from that post..  
Its a good day!!!